# C++ Inheritance - why my function was not used?

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance, virtual

I have a `IBase` class with `virtual void CastData(){}` in it. there it is used in another function.

I have another totally unrelated class `IC` with

```
virtual void CastData(){
    for (FunctionIterator it(funcs.begin()); it != funcs.end(); ++it){
        DataType dataCopy;
        dataCopy = *dataElement;
        (*it)(dataCopy);
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a new class where CastData from C will overrite CastData from base class.

So I try something like
class IGraphElement : public IBase, public IC

All functions from  run correctly. and all IC functions run but IBase CastData was not overwritten.

How to do such types of overrites when virtual functions from class you inherit overrite virtual functions from another class you inherit?

Comment: May I ask why you can't name your functions better?

Comment: All this english description is confusing. When not provide compilable code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, having two base class with two functions that have the same signature should result in ambiguous call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtual functions must be overriden by a derived class, not another base class.  Perhaps provide an override in IGraphElement that calls into IC to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the CastData for all, then you may needs to abstract an interface and make IC and IBase derive from the same interface. But as you point out, IBase and IC totally unrelated class, then you should not expect IGraphElement can override CastData in IBase and IC gracefully.